# angular2 with path location (instead of hash location)

Tags: iis-7, angular2-routing

i would like to use routing strategy in angular2 with no hash (#).
i'm using RouterModule by
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: false, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})

Now, i'm trying to configure my app to run via IIS as an application but i cannot run it in my browser (no matter whether i use a hash in the url or not).
i get this error:

vendor.ddeb5398c00029f474f6.bundle.js:20 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'rren/'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'rren/'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost/rren/vendor.ddeb5398c00029f474f6.bundle.js:27:26216)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? how to fix it? any ideas? 
i'm using IIS7 and nodejs 6.2.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Liran

Comment: I tried to install Url Rewriting that allows redirecting and url rewriting in iis 7 but i'm not sure whether i configure it correctly or not.
do i need to rewrite the url from localhost/rren/logon to localhost/rren/#/logon   ?

or maybe i need just to rewrite from localhost/rren/logon to localhost/rren/index.html ?

does angularyjs starts the loading flow by loading the index.html? how does it know to go to the logon page? this is what i should simulate using the url rewriting tool..

thanks again for everybody!
Liran

Comment: Can you update your question with snippet of web.config settings you have configured till now for routing purposes? And yes, index.html is the start point of the app. So your URL routing in web.config (or global.asax if you have a dummy .Net web application setup for this purpose) does need to be configured to point all routes, e.g. 'localhost/angular-app/', 'localhost/angular-app/home/dashboard/' or any other child routes to default to index.html in your virtual application/directory in IIS. The exception would be CSS n JS resources. So, you'll need another route rule in your config file.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if URL routing/rewrite is automatically supported in IIS 7, but if not, it needs isapi.dll to be setup. Anyway... you can figure that out yourself easily. Lots of articles on the net. Here's one I found by doing a quick search: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module